# amazon simpleDB query

Tags: php, amazon-simpledb

i am trying to create a query on my simpleDB. here is the query:

```
select * from flyers where eventDate >= '20120101' and clubId= '0001' OR clubId = '0002' ORDER BY eventDate asc limit 20
```

the problem is with:

```
clubId= '0001' OR clubId = '0002'
```

i get the error: [Invalid sort expression. The sort attribute must be present in at least one of the predicates, and the predicate cannot contain the is null operator.]

i would also like to be able to have up to 20 'OR''s chained together if it is possible

Comment: Try this: `select * from flyers where eventDate >= '20120101' and clubId in('0001','0002') ORDER BY eventDate asc limit 20`. Does that fix your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as daan kindly pointed out:

```
select * from flyers where eventDate >= '20120101' and clubId in('0001','0002') ORDER BY eventDate asc limit 20
```